# selecting a specific array in unity

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

{

```
private static string[] lesson1 = { "f", "j" };
private static string[] lesson2 = { "k", "d" };
private static string[] lesson3 = { "f", "j", "k", "d" };

public static string GetRandomWord() // return a random word of our choosing
{
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, lesson3.Length); // get random index assocciated with one of the words in the list
    string randomWord = lesson3[randomIndex]; //uses the index to find a string

    return randomWord;
}
```

}

under random index - random range I have lesson3 hard-coded in. How can I fix this so when the user selects say lesson 2 the array is swapped so it would be(keep in mind the selection is done in another scene so the information needs to carry over:

```
 int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, lesson2.Length);
```

any insites would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping close to your current implementation you could add a static value that indicates which lesson to use and add an array of lessons.  This is an array of arrays.

```
private static int lessonNumber = 1;

private static string[] lesson1 = { "f", "j" };
private static string[] lesson2 = { "k", "d" };
private static string[] lesson3 = { "f", "j", "k", "d" };

private static string[][] allLessons = {
    lesson1,
    lesson2,
    lesson3
}

// the new lessonNumber should be 1 to 3 (or more if you add more)
public static void SetLessonNumber(int newLessonNumber) {
    lessonNumber = newLessonNumber;
}

public static string GetRandomWord() // return a random word of our choosing
{
    string[] lesson = allLessons[lessonNumber-1];
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, lesson.Length); // get random index assocciated with one of the words in the list
    string randomWord = lesson[randomIndex]; //uses the index to find a string

    return randomWord;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and making it easy for me to understand. It works exactly how I needed it to.